# Dealing with "the requested PHP extension pdo_sqlite is missing from your system. " when running composer install

Tags: php, jenkins, composer-php

I'm having difficulty running `composer install` on Jenkins.

I have a Jenkins job that I need to run `composer install` for.  I have installed php7.2 and composer.  When I run the command, I get the following errors:

`composer install`

```
  Problem 1
- teamtnt/tntsearch v1.3.2 requires ext-pdo_sqlite * -> the requested PHP extension pdo_sqlite is missing from your system.
- teamtnt/tntsearch v1.3.2 requires ext-pdo_sqlite * -> the requested PHP extension pdo_sqlite is missing from your system.
- Installation request for teamtnt/tntsearch v1.3.2 -> satisfiable by teamtnt/tntsearch[v1.3.2].
```

So I install sqlite using the following command: `sudo apt-get install php7.2-sqlite3`

After this, I get the additional warning, and the error persists.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite.so' 
(tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlite.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlite.so: 
undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name), /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlite.so.so
(/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlite.so.so: cannot open shared object file: 
No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- teamtnt/tntsearch v1.3.2 requires ext-pdo_sqlite * -> the requested PHP extension pdo_sqlite is missing from your system.
- teamtnt/tntsearch v1.3.2 requires ext-pdo_sqlite * -> the requested PHP extension pdo_sqlite is missing from your system.
- Installation request for teamtnt/tntsearch v1.3.2 -> satisfiable by teamtnt/tntsearch[v1.3.2].
```

**When I ssh into the Jenkins box and run `composer install` from the workspace directory, everything runs as expected and the vendor directory is generated with no errors.**

I have spent a lot of time looking at the answers to existing questions on StackOverflow.

I've purged everything that is not php7.2, and removed any previous versions of my machine.
I have also installed the php7.2-pdo_sqlite, and ensured that it is displayed in the php.ini file.
I've also tried completely removing php (and checked using `php -v`) and then reinstalled php7.2.
When I run `php --ini` I see /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini, and 
/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini displayed on the list.

I have also given READ permissions to /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlite.so incase it was due to a permission error.

What else can I do to resolve the error above? - my goal is to be able to run composer install.

Comment: Does `php -v` show the correct version?  Sounds like your command line php may be different than what the web server is using.

Comment: Check the module is loaded, use `php -m` to see the list of modules loaded / installed.

Comment: @Devon the result of `php -v` is `PHP 7.2.6-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)`, I am expecting php v7.2 so I believe this is correct.

Comment: Thanks @steadweb - the result of `php -m` returns `pdo_sqlite` in the list, so I believe that it is installed already.  Not sure why I would have errors relating to this extension.

Comment: Is it normal to have  /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlite.so.so (double .so)?

Comment: Does jenkins have access to pdo_sqlite ??...When you run a job from jenkins, it generally runs with a user called `jenkins`,so jenkins might not have access to run/execute pdo_sqlite ...since you did say you can do it fine when doing an SSH

Comment: @jeremy I'm not sure why it is referencing pdo_sqlite.so.so, when I check the directory /usr/lib/php/20170718/ the file has a single .so - /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlite.so

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the extension?

Comment: Thanks @jeremy, yes I tried this, and I updated the question with the exact errors that occurred after the sqlite installation commands.

Comment: by reinstalling i meant remove et install, do you have only one version of php installed?

Comment: @jeremy yes, I used `apt-get purge` to completely remove all versions of php (7.0 possibly and 7.0). and then reinstalled php 7.2 only.

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround

If your build pipeline doesn't require `sqlite` to be installed, you can bypass the check for platform requirements with `--ignore-platform-reqs`, like so:

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

From the [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install):

> --ignore-platform-reqs: ignore php, hhvm, lib-* and ext-* requirements and force the installation even if the local machine does not fulfill
>   these. See also the platform config option.

***If you have tests that assert `sqlite` functionality, this isn't a solution, unfortunately.***

Comment: Thanks @steadweb - I would love to be able to use this workaround to be able to run `composer install` sadly, there are tests that assert sqlite.  So I'm still looking for a solution.